# Data Retrieval is not in the given order?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

greetings all
i am using spring framework and hibernate to communicate with database
i have a table that contain some records suppose with ids 1,2,3,4,5
when i tried to make an HQL query to retrieve the data ordered by id asc
data is retrieved in a correct order,but when trying to loop on the data with enhanced for loop, the order is reversed, i don't know why ???????

```
List<MyDTO> data = getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery(
                        "from MyDTO where indicator=:indicator order by entityId")
                .setLong("indicator", 10).list();
        System.out.println("First Id In The Query: "
                + data.get(0).getEntityId()); // prints 1
```

when making for loop on them the order is reversed

```
for (MyDTO myObj : data) {
System.out.println("Id: " + myObj.getEntityId());
}
// prints 5,4,3,2,1
```

any ideas why such behavior occurs ?

Comment: The above appears to be correct. Can you show your handling of the list afterwards?

Comment: making a simple for loop on the list to sysout the id of each object

Comment: @ Gary Rowe,i edited the post above,any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asc` is the default order, so you can omit that.

Otherwise it should work as expected. Make sure you are iterating the list properly.

Comment: @sword101 this is extremely strange. Could you please print data.getClass() and tell the result

Comment: Problem solved after installing a fresh copy of tomcat, seems that everything was okay in the code.

Comment: @sword101 good. I guess you can retain the accepted mark, since my answer was technically correct, and I couldn't see through your deployment environment ;)